# Is there a way to determine the width and height of a WPF Window before showing it?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, height, width

I am trying to center a WPF Window on the current position of the mouse cursor.  Getting the mouse coordinates is no problem, but I need to determine the width and height of the window in order to calculate the offset for setting the 'Left' and 'Top' properties.

Is there a way to determine the width and height of a window before showing it (calling the 'Show' method)?

I have 'SizeToContent' set to true on my window so that the content determines the actual window size.  I have already tried calling 'Measure' and was expecting this to set 'DesiredSize' but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call Show() first and then center it on the current position of the mouse cursor?